# Need to capture the client ip address behind the proxy

Tags: java, servlets, proxy, http-headers, http-proxy

I am currently trying to get the IP address of the client when it's trying to hit the server behind the proxy in java.. I tried all the following but doesn't seem to work . It works only when there is no proxy

```
Using getRemoteAddr() method
"X-FORWARDED-FOR"
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"
"HTTP_X_FORWARDED"
"HTTP_X_CLUSTER_CLIENT_IP"
"HTTP_CLIENT_IP"
"HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"
"HTTP_FORWARDED"
"HTTP_VIA"
"REMOTE_ADDR"
```

Comment: What proxy are you using? Is it configured to actually set those headers? For example, if you are using NGINX as a reverse-proxy, you must also configure it to set the "X-Forwarded-For" header. You can also check the "X-Real-IP" header.

Comment: I am not sure which proxy is getting used.. as its a uat server which I do not have access too .. it doesnt happen in my local ... it happens only when i am trying to access the app deployed on the uat server. getRemoteAddr() method gives me the proxy ip.. i am not sure what can be done here

Comment: Can you inspect the headers of the HTTP Request?

Comment: I fixed this issue .. i found the x-forwaded-for was just x-forwarded...and hence was returning me null for the value..i am not sure who configured it wrong

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I fixed this issue .. i found the x-forwaded-for was just x-forwarded...and hence was returning me null for the value..i am not sure who configured it wrong